# Creating a schema called 'master'

Tags: sql-server

I've created a schema called master in SS2008, however every time I type in the word, it's formatted as blue, rather than black. Should I be worried? I've checked the reserved word list, and it doesn't seem to be on there.

Comment: [`master`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) is a database in sql server that contains all of the system info.  I personally would change the schema name to something else to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably thinks you are refering to the system database which is named `master`.  I would think that is Master is a reserved keyword.  Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173443%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to what the various color mean.

```
Red - Character string

Dark Green - Comment

Black, Silver Background - SQLCMD command 

Magenta - System function

Green - System table

Blue - Keyword

Teal - Line numbers or template parameter

Maroon - SQL Server stored procedure

Dark Grey - Operators
```

Answer (score 1):

It is highlighted blue because master is one of the four system databases in sql server - master, model, msdb, and tempdb.

Answer (score 0):

Master is one of the system databases and to reduce confusion should be modified for clarity.  Also the SQL parser may first look in the system master database before realizing that your referring to your schema.  I know this applies if 'sys' is used when naming objects.